# iText - Pass Objects

Tags: java, itext

I am providing the scenario as an image, which I guess would help in better understandability.

[image]

Here I have to pass object from different `Swing` forms and accumulate it to create a new document which will consist the concatenated texts, tables etc.

My question, is it possible to do the same.

**N.B :-** I am able to do simple tasks in iText - reading tables from `Swing` forms, etc.

Thanks, suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: What technology are your forms? PDF, too or something like Swing or JSF?

Comment: Yes, they are made in `Swing`

Comment: @hinneLinks ; the problem here is that there are inputs from different forms, otherwise the pdf construction is quiet easy if they are sent at once. Moreover `PdfStamper` is quiet good where they can read existing pdf, but doing that programatically for n number of pdfs wont be optimum I guess

Comment: @mustangDC The question is unclear as mkl indicates in the comments to the (correct) answer from Balaji. Please update your question. If you can read tables from swing forms and do simple tasks in iText such as creating `PdfPTable`s, then what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is : I have different `JPanel`, which has a table and a `JTextBox` each, from where I must take input and print it to a single pdf document. On the whole **Accumulate all `JPanel` data and print into one document**

Comment: Hope it is clearer now @BrunoLowagie

Comment: @mustangDC When you say *Accumulate all `JPanel` data and print into one document*, do you really only mean the **data** (unstyled content values) which you want to add to the document in an independent style? In that case you should ask a separate question on how to generically extract data from generic Swing components and tag it accordingly. Or do you want to add the Swing **component** appearance as is to the document? In that case use the iText `Graphics2D` interface.

Comment: No it isn't. I still don't know (1) if you want to take each `JPanel` as a whole and create a `PdfTemplate` for each `JPanel` using `PdfGraphics2D` (which is feasible, but not very elegant), or (2) if you want to extract data from the `JPanel`, and create iText objects using that data. In case of (1), you'd add the templates to the `Document`; in case of (2) you'd add the iText objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do the same with `itext`.  May be you can do it this way

- Create `document`
- Get Form 1 Values. Create a `Chunk` using the Form 1 Text.
- Add the `Chunk` into the `Document`
- Get Form 2 Values. Create a `Chunk` using Form 2 text
- Add the `Chunk` into the `Document`

Like this do for all the forms.

The above is solution for adding all the text from different forms into document.

Refer [Link](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=1) for `itext` references.

If in case all the texts has to concatenated do it well ahead and add it to the Chunk.

P.S: Am not familiar with `Swing` framework.

Comment: Yes, I have tried your solution, but scenario is a bit different, where the Swing GUI form contains tables and text boxes. and there may be n number of forms with n number of tables.

Comment: @mustangDC In that case the image in your question is somewhat misleading because it seems to indicate that merely text but not structures  from the Swing components are to be copied to the PDF.

Comment: Yes you are partially correct, that might be misleading `but is there any difference if I extract text/tables/label text etc. from a GUI component` . They all are same, it just depends on the GUI form and its components

Comment: @mustangDC The difference is that according to the image I would imagine a solution which merely retrieves text strings from each of the components and styles these strings while adding them to the PDF using iText styling capabilities. When you now say you want to add the components as they are, I would more think about using the iText capability of providing `Graphics2D` instances to directly render the Swing components to.

Comment: @mustangDC Not sure if SWING GUIs is rendered as HTML Page. If So refer http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=55 for converting html to PDF.